# My fuschia is dying after pruning

Tags: diagnosis, pruning, repair, pinching-out

We have a home garden and recently fuschia was added to our collection. it was all great looking and healthy but after a few days there were no blooms and it was all leaves on the plant. I did read some articles Googling the issue, and they suggested pruning or pinching. I did cut off some stems to encourage blooming two days ago and it dried out and is dying! I try to keep the soil moist and It is getting all of the daylight hours of bright, indirect light. The temp. in the house is about 27-30 (C). Here are the photos before and after the issue:

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you post some pictures so we can see the health of your fuschia

Comment: Picture please, including of the pot - it doesn't sound like you're watering enough, and it might be the pot is too small or isn't draining freely

Comment: I just added some photos, but I suspect they're too large!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your fuschia is dying from pruning.  Not at all.  Bummer.  Need you to answer some questions to find out what is really happening.  Looks to me like you transplanted a fuschia into a larger pot.  The plant size works with that pot...enough.

Did you use potting soil or garden soil?

Did you put gravel or rock below the soil and above the drainage hole?

How often do you water and what precipitates watering again?

Did you add anything to the soil?

Is this pot indoors or outdoors?

Have you sprayed anything on this plant?

What did you add for fertilizer and how soon after purchase?

The biggest question is...why did you prune this plant so hard?  You didn't 'over prune' but this is really out of the ordinary to cut up a beautiful, blooming plant like this when most people are reluctant to even remove flowers??!

There is something you haven't told us.

My initial feeling is that you used garden soil, possibly a layer of rock at the bottom, you added manure not thoroughly decomposed?  What I am looking at is a plant unable to uptake moisture even though there is plenty of moisture.  Root rot?  Perched water table from that erroneous layer of 'drainage' rock below the soil?  Soil way too compact for air and drainage?  Hey I could be dead wrong 'cause I only see what your pictures tell me.  Just trying to instigate questions that would give us more information!

I would dump out your soil, get a smaller pot or use the original after cleaning with bleach, transplant using just potting soil no compost no garden soil no additives including fertilizer.  For right now.  Cut the stumps back to the main stem.  Moist not wet soil, no full sun, no hard wind.  See what happens.  This plant looks very unhappy.  Take a look at the roots.  What do they look like?  Bright white (I doubt not) or mushy ends or brown or tan coloring?  Are there lots of fine roots or just a glob of brownish roots sitting in very wet soil?

More information!  Please.  I really really want to know why you pruned your plant, please tell us.  Something happened that made you want to cut it back like that.  Hey if everything was fine for the plant; drainage, light, good soil from a bag, a tiny bit of fertilizer pruning like this would not hurt this plant and your plant should be vigorous and happy.  Something went wrong and you pruned it because there was another problem altogether pruning wouldn't fix.  That is my guess at this point.  The only way to learn this stuff is by making mistakes.  Or at least asking those of us who have made more mistakes than you are able to imagine!  Grins!

Comment: ...and too much nitrogen could stop the blooming, gosh need more information.  This plant is indoors?  When you purchased this plant was it indoors or out of doors?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is, I did not transplant the fuschia. The soil is also the same as what it was when I purchased it. I water it once a day and the soil seems to be wet whenever I checked. The pot is indoors and it was out of doors in the place I originally purchased it from. I didn't add anything, didn't spray anything. The thing I have done was pruning plus pinching old blooms from the plant. I pruned it because there were no blooms for a couple of days and did it to encourage blooming as I said.

Comment: Is it possible to save the plant?

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer and I know it's useless for this plant, however, I think it might serve some other time for a different plant.

Pruning promotes new growth, but it takes time for the plant to flower again. This happens because after pruning new stems will emerge, then new leaves, and only after that - new flowers.

After pruning the plants need less water because they have less leaves. If the soil is constantly wet, the plant doesn't manage to absorb the water, therefore its roots will rot.

I have pruned my fuchsia to a 6 cm stem and new shoots formed. Your plant didn't suffer because of pruning, but because of something else. Fuchsia and Impatiens start wilting when they experience hot weather and drought. By all means, they need to be gradually accustomed to their normal water intake. Overwatering already stressed plants makes things worse.